# XeLaTeX: force lining numbers (instead of old style ones) in math bold mode, for fonts that don't have boldface

Tags: fonts, xetex, unicode-math

Consider the following code:

```
% !TeX program = xelatex
\documentclass[12pt,a4paper]{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{amsmath,amsthm,amssymb,amsfonts}

% STIX Two font
\usepackage[math-style=ISO]{unicode-math}
\usepackage{xltxtra}
\setmainfont[Numbers=OldStyle]{STIX Two Text}
\setmathfont{STIX Two Math}

\begin{document}

\begin{tabular}{lll}
    text   & A = 1              & \textit{B = 0}          \\
    textbf & \textbf{A = 1}     & \textbf{\textit{B = 0}} \\
    math   & $A = 1$            & $\mathit{B = 0}$        \\
    mathbf & $\mathbf{A = 1}$   & $\mathbf{B = 0}$        \\
    symbf  & $\symbf{A = 1}$    & $\symbf{B = 0}$
\end{tabular}

\end{document}
```

Results:

[image]

As you can see, in a normal math environment (i.e. between `$$`), the numbers are of lining style (c.f. 3rd line). But if the numbers are in `\mathbf` or `\mathit` then they have the old style (c.f. 3rd line and 4th line), which is ugly for me. The reason is, I guess, that the STIX Two Math font does not have bold face or italic face.

I can use `\symbf` and `\symit` instead, but then my code will be invalid if e.g. I switch back to LaTeX (instead of XeLaTeX).

My question is: **How to force `\mathbf` to use lining-style numbers?** (Only numbers and not letters.)

Thank you very much in advance for your help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One solution is to use `\symbfup` rather than `\symbf`.  This gets you bold upright symbols, rather than ISO-style bold italic.  That is probably what you wanted.  (If you consistently want to use upright letters, consider setting `math-style` to something other than `ISO`.)

To answer the literal question you asked, you want to use [`\setmathrm` from `fontspec`,](http://ctan.math.utah.edu/ctan/tex-archive/macros/latex/contrib/fontspec/fontspec.pdf#1b) which the `unicode-math` package includes.  Give it the `BoldFont=` and `BoldFeatures=` options, as with `\newfontfamily`.

```
% !TeX program = xelatex
\documentclass[12pt,a4paper]{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}

% STIX Two font
\usepackage[math-style=ISO]{unicode-math}
\setmainfont[Numbers=OldStyle]{STIX Two Text}
\setmathfont{STIX Two Math}
\setmathrm{STIX Two Text}[
  UprightFeatures={Numbers=OldStyle},
  BoldFont = STIX Two Text Bold,
  BoldFeatures={Numbers=Lining}]
\setboldmathrm{STIX Two Text Bold}[Numbers=Lining]

\begin{document}

\begin{tabular}{lll}
    text   & A = 1              & \textit{B = 0}          \\
    textbf & \textbf{A = 1}     & \textbf{\textit{B = 0}} \\
    math   & $A = 1$            & $\mathit{B = 0}$        \\
    mathbf & $\mathbf{A = 1}$   & $\mathbf{B = 0}$        \\
    symbf  & $\symbf{A = 1}$    & $\symbf{B = 0}$
\end{tabular}

\end{document}
```

[image: Sample Text]

I went ahead and set `\setboldmathrm` as well (the `\mathrm` font for bold-style math).  You will get some harmless warning messages about how the font does not support uppercase numbers.  You can suppress those by removing `BoldFeatures={Numbers=Lining}` and `[Numbers=Lining]`.

I also removed a couple of packages you weren’t using for this example.  Please note: you shouldn’t load `inputenc` in the TeX engines that support `unicode-math`, nor should you load `amsfonts` and `amssymb` if you are going to load an OpenType math font over them.

Comment: A detailed answer, with advice on good practice one should follow. This is a typical excellent answer that I expect. Since I cannot upvote twice, I found another answer (also excellent) from you to upvote. Thanks a lot!

Comment: @Khue Thanks. For future reference, you can upvote twice, once you get a little more karma, by awarding a bounty.